# ImageMagick .NET Round Image(s) overlap issue

Tags: c#, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, magick.net

Hey all I have the following C# code:

```
List<string> lFiles = new List<string>();

lFiles.Add(@"C:\Users\David\Pictures\1.jpg");
lFiles.Add(@"C:\Users\David\Pictures\2.jpg");
lFiles.Add(@"C:\Users\David\Pictures\3.jpg");
IFiles.Add(@"C:\Users\David\Pictures\4.jpg");
IFiles.Add(@"C:\Users\David\Pictures\5.jpg");

using (MagickImageCollection images = new MagickImageCollection())
{
    MagickImage magickinput = null;

    foreach (string tempFile in lFiles)
    {
       magickinput = new MagickImage(tempFile);

       magickinput.Alpha(AlphaOption.Set);
       magickinput.Quality = 100;
       magickinput.Resize(0, 100);
       magickinput.Distort(DistortMethod.DePolar, 0);
       magickinput.VirtualPixelMethod = VirtualPixelMethod.HorizontalTile;
       magickinput.BackgroundColor = MagickColors.None;
       magickinput.Distort(DistortMethod.Polar, 0);                        
       images.Add(magickinput);
   }

   var montageSettings = new MontageSettings()
   {
       BackgroundColor = MagickColors.None,
       TileGeometry = new MagickGeometry(lFiles.Count, 1),
       Shadow = true,
       Geometry = new MagickGeometry(-10, 5, 0, 0)
   };

   using (IMagickImage result = images.Montage(montageSettings))
   {
       result.Composite(magickinput, CompositeOperator.DstIn);
       result.Trim();
       result.RePage();

       result.Write(@"C:\Users\David\Pictures\combinedImgs.png");
   }
}
```

This produces an image like this:

[image]

Notice that the area around Maggie (the first image) has Lisa (the second image) within it and cuts out some of image 2???. It also cuts off Marge (last image). If I just set **Geometry = new MagickGeometry(-10, 5, 0, 0)** to **Geometry = new MagickGeometry(5, 5, 0, 0)** it then looks like this:

[image]

Which fixes Marge (last image) but Maggie (first image) still looks odd...

I've also noticed that all the images seem to be "fuzzy" with their outlines:

[image]
[image]

First image is the original and the second is the Magick version.

Images used:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Maggie (first image) by herself looks like this:

[image]

What am I doing incorrectly? I'm using version ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16.

And this is the overall look i am going for:

[image]

**UPDATE**

This is as far as i have gotten with translating the command line:

```
List<string> lFiles = new List<string>();

lFiles.Add(@"C:\Users\David\Pictures\1.jpg");
lFiles.Add(@"C:\Users\David\Pictures\2.jpg");
lFiles.Add(@"C:\Users\David\Pictures\3.jpg");
lFiles.Add(@"C:\Users\David\Pictures\4.jpg");
lFiles.Add(@"C:\Users\David\Pictures\5.jpg");

using (MagickImageCollection images = new MagickImageCollection())
{
       MagickImage magickinput = null;

       foreach (string tempFile in lFiles)
       {
            magickinput = new MagickImage(tempFile);
            IMagickImage _circle = new MagickImage();

            magickinput.Resize(100, 100);
            _circle = new MagickImage(MagickColor.FromRgb(255, 255, 255), magickinput.Width + 20, magickinput.Height);
            _circle.Draw(new DrawableCircle(50, 50, 50, 100));
            _circle.Alpha(AlphaOption.Off);
            //_circle.Compose....????

      }
}
```

I'm not sure how to do these following commands in C#:

> xc:black
>
> copy_opacity -layers
>
> dstover -layers
>
> xc:"graya(100%,0)"
>
> +smush

**UPDATE 2**

[image]

Comment: What version of Imagemagick and please post your input images. Does the same think happen with -smush that than montage?

Comment: Can you also add the desired output?

Comment: Updated my OP to show what I am looking to achieve.

Comment: Updated my OP to show my C# code I have so far @dlemstra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a different approach using Imagemagick 6 (unix syntax). I resize the images, then create a circle mask, then put that circle into the alpha channel of each image using -layers composite with the null: separator, then smush the images together.

```
convert maggie.jpg lisa.jpg bart.jpg homer.jpg marge.jpg -resize 100x100 \
null: \
\( -size 100x100 xc:black -fill white -draw "circle 50,50 50,88" \) \
-alpha off -compose copy_opacity -layers composite \
null: \
\( -size 100x100 xc:none -fill black -draw "circle 50,50 50,90" -blur 0x5 \) \
-compose dstover -layers composite \
-background none -gravity center +smush -25+0 \
simpsons_circles2.png
```

[image]

See
https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_mods/#composite_single
https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#layers
https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#smush

And that would translate into the following C# code (provided by dlemstra):

```
List<string> lFiles = new List<string>();

lFiles.Add(@"C:\Users\David\Pictures\1.jpg");
lFiles.Add(@"C:\Users\David\Pictures\2.jpg");
lFiles.Add(@"C:\Users\David\Pictures\3.jpg");
lFiles.Add(@"C:\Users\David\Pictures\4.jpg");
lFiles.Add(@"C:\Users\David\Pictures\5.jpg");

using (MagickImageCollection images = new MagickImageCollection())
{
    foreach (string tempFile in lFiles)
    {
        images.Add(tempFile);
    }

    using (var mask = new MagickImage("xc:black", 100, 100))
    {
        mask.Settings.FillColor = MagickColors.White;
        mask.Draw(new DrawableCircle(50, 50, 50, 88));
        mask.HasAlpha = false;

        foreach (var image in images)
        {
            image.Resize(100, 100);

            image.Composite(mask, CompositeOperator.CopyAlpha);
        }
    }

    using (var shadow = new MagickImage("xc:none", 100, 100))
    {
        shadow.Settings.FillColor = MagickColors.Black;
        shadow.Draw(new DrawableCircle(50, 50, 50, 90));
        shadow.Blur(0, 5);

        foreach (var image in images)
        {
            image.Composite(shadow, CompositeOperator.DstOver);
        }
    }

    images.First().BackgroundColor = MagickColors.None;

    using (IMagickImage result = images.SmushHorizontal(-25))
    {
        result.Write(@"C:\Users\David\Pictures\combinedImgs.png");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is missing the shadow

Comment: `@dlemstra` Right, sorry about that. I will fix it shortly.

Comment: Also, If you look at yours, Marge (last image) seems to be cut off as well like mine was.

Comment: Yeah i'm not doing well converting the command line above to C# @dlemstra

Comment: Guys can I please get some assistance with converting this to C#?

Comment: Thanks for the code, @dlemstra and fmw42. There seems to be an error once it gets to **image.Resize(100, 100);**. It seems to freeze the program and just stays there.

Comment: @StealthRT That will only happen the first time you run that. ImageMagick will benchmark your GPU and CPU.

Comment: @dlemstra I've waited for 30+ minutes and it still has not progressed to the next step **(image.Composite(mask, CompositeOperator.CopyAlpha);)**. See my OP for the image.